# How do I match the correct strings while keeping capture groups the same?

Tags: python, regex

I began with the regex: `^(S?g?[mfds]|S?G*g[msdf])$` and I converted it to: `^(S?)(G*)(g?)(m|s|d|f|)$`
to separate capture groups into (S, G, g, m/f/d/s)

this is the link to what I am supposed to match and what I should not match: https://regex101.com/r/q8b7zJ/1

I tried solving this by having `(g?|G*g)` in the second capture group to prevent `Gm` from matching, however, my capture groups end up becoming `(S, Gg, '', msdf)`

How do I match the correct strings while keeping my capture groups the same `(S, G, g, m/s/d/f)`

Comment: If you do not use PyPi regex library, all you can do is use `^(S?)(?:(g?)|(G*)(g))([mfds])$` and then check if Group 3 and 4 or Group 2 matched anything.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `Gm` from matching, you might use a negative lookahead `(?!G[mfds])` to rule out the matches for `G` followed by any of `m` `f` `d` `d`

```
import re

strings = [
    "m",
    "gf",
    "Ggm",
    "GGgf",
    "Ss",
    "SGgs",
    "mf",
    "Gm",
    "SSm",
    "GSm"
]

pattern = r"^(S?)(?!G[mfds])(G*)(g?)([mfds])$"
for s in strings:
    m = re.match(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(m.groups())
```

Output

```
('', '', '', 'm')
('', '', 'g', 'f')
('', 'G', 'g', 'm')
('', 'GG', 'g', 'f')
('S', '', '', 's')
('S', 'G', 'g', 's')
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QAWItQ/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/icE0Cw).